# TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float' while plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a graph having 3 points on Y and time on x-axis. The data is given as:

```
0.00059642,0.00060012,0.00059642,0.00060012,1112.25854421,2017-10-11T19:45:00,0.66505583
0.00060011,0.00060012,0.00059642,0.00059922,3637.58805798,2017-10-11T19:50:00,2.17918273
0.00059922,0.00059999,0.00059922,0.00059922,395.62320194,2017-10-11T19:55:00,0.23722457
0.00059922,0.00059999,0.00058506,0.00059518,4551.22115392,2017-10-11T20:00:00,2.70701959
```

Code is given below:

```
time = data['T']
data['T'] = pd.to_datetime(time)
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5))
plt.plot(data['Close'], lw=1, label='ARK CLOSE')
plt.plot(data['MA_5'], 'g', lw=1, label='5-day SMA (green)')
plt.plot(data['MA_20'], 'y', lw=2, label='20-day SMA (red)')
plt.xticks(data['T'])
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

on `xticks` I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot transform `timestamp` to a numeric value required to define the position on the axis. However, you do not need this since you just want constant distances, as I understand it.

You can do

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), data["T"], rotation=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about letting matplotlib take care of the dates on the x axis,

```
data['T'] = pd.to_datetime(data['T'])
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5))
plt.plot(data['T'],data['Close'], lw=1, label='ARK CLOSE')
plt.plot(data['T'],data['MA_5'], 'g', lw=1, label='5-day SMA (green)')
plt.plot(data['T'],data['MA_20'], 'y', lw=2, label='20-day SMA (red)')

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
plt.show()
```